# Setting a different timezone for client in javascript

Tags: javascript, native

I wanted to know if this is possible?

I looked everywhere and I don't want to change the time integer of the Date object because I use it at service requests.

I encounter this problem with some other devices. 
new Date() from device returns `Fri Nov 02 2018 09:27:33 GMT+0200 (EET)`
and new Date() from chrome returns `Fri Nov 02 2018 10:27:33 GMT+0200 (EET)`

but new Date().getTime() from device and new Date().getTime() from chrome returns same value and I want this value to stay like this.

Comment: Wait you want something closer to the UTC timestamp, or do you want it to display as a different time zone?

Comment: @RobertMennell I want it to display a different time zone when "new Date()" is called

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString this will do the trick if you know the locale, and if not you can set the timezone manually

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question to this one, so i sugest you to browser or to click on this link so you can view enought answers to your preocupation.
Thanks for following the link and upvoting this answers so it can help other to trust the link

[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like Moment-js and Moment-timezone js

I wrote a example code

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>time of My Country is <span id="mycountryTime"></span></div>
        <div>time of New York is <span id="newyorkTime"></span></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){    
            var mycountryTime = moment();
            var newyorkTime   = moment.tz(moment(), "America/New_York");

            $('#mycountryTime').html(mycountryTime.format());
            $('#newyorkTime').html(newyorkTime.format());
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

moment-js is for formatting date.
moment-timezone js is for getting date based on timezone.

more details on this are in https://momentjs.com/docs/

I hope it would be helpful.

---

and you don't need to set date for everywhere
each client's browser will make date about their own country